# jQuery Replace a word but not within images and documents

Tags: jquery, replace

I currently have the following code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var html = $('#wrapper').html();
    $('#wrapper').html(html.replace(/hello/gi, 'hello<sup>&#174;</sup>'));
});
```

How can i add the 'not' function so that it does not replace the 'hello' when it is within images or is tied to document names?

So for example, i do want 'hello' to be replaced everywhere on the page, but not when in

```
<img src="path/hello.jpg"/>
```

or

```
<a href="path/documents/hello.pdf">test</a>
```

Comment: Do you only want to replace the word in the text, or do you actually want to change the markup as well, just not these specific cases?

Comment: Yes, most ideal would be that it replaces all the text on the page but does not replace the text within href or image links

Answer (score 1):

You could grab all elements from within the body, iterate over them, find if they have a text node, get their `text()` value and then modify the HTML based off of what was grabbed in the text. This completely avoids inner attribute values and you won't to negate text within `a` elements.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body *').each(function () {
        var children = this.childNodes;
        if (children.length === 1) {
            if (children[0].nodeType === 3) {
                var text = $(this).text();
                $(this).html(text.replace(/((H|h)ello)/gi, '$1<sup>&#174;</sup>'));
            }

        }
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cwalkdawg/K9kdg/1/)

Comment: Thanks ChristopherW for the reply, tried the code but it does not seem to work - try putting a div around the html and you will see

Comment: Noticed something - if i add that word inside a span within a 'p 'and within a 'div', it doesn't work.. <div>test test  <p>Hello <span>Hello</span></p> </div>